# building opencv from trunk makes cv2.so, how to get cv.so?

Tags: opencv

Simplecv depends on cv.so, but when I build open opencv from trunk I only get cv2.so

I've not heard back from either opencv or Simplecv. Any here have an idea?

Ubuntu 12.10 64bit desktop, build args: 
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D BUILD_DOCS=ON

Thanks,
Kent

Comment: If you are using master branch, you won't get cv.so. It is removed and no longer supported. Use opencv 2.x version. You will get both.

Comment: Just use the OpenCV Python binding and forget SimpleCV. IMO SimpleCV is more trouble than it is worth.